# How to get vue-router to work inside component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-component

I have the following index.html

```
<html>

....
<section id="#section">
<router-view></router-view>
</section>
</html>
```

In a template file I have the following which is loading at "/"

```
<div>
    <a v-on:click="go()">GO</a>
</div>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            go: function () {
                this.$router.go("/app")
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and I have the following route map

```
route.map({
    '/': {component: a},
    "/app": {component:b}
})
route.start(a,"#section")
```

clicking on the link doesn't seem to change the view. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Even using

```
 route.map({'/': {component: a, subRoutes: { '/app': component: b }}}
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `'/app': component: b` in `route.map({'/': {component: a, subRoutes: { '/app': component: b }}}` isn't right.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            go: function () {
                this.$router.go("/app")
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I think it should be `this.$router.go`, not `this.$route.router.go`

It also looks like you're calling in the wrong component. It should be `<router-view></router-view>` not `<route-view></route-view>`

http://router.vuejs.org/en/view.html

Comment: @Kendall what doesn't work? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @jonathan this.$route.router.go('/app') nor this.$router.go('/app')

Comment: ...that's just it....no errors. the hash changes but not the DOM content

Comment: Updated my answer. Looks like you're not calling the correct component.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with the fact that <router-view> tag gets replace with the said component?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack project boilerplate to build this vuejs app

Comment: if the <router-view> tag is being replaced would this proven the components from being switched? is the router instance a operate instance from what is being instantiated?